# SVG isn't being displayed

Tags: html, css, svg

I need dotted lines. `<hr>` won't do as there needs to be more space between dots, unless there's a way to achieve that through CSS? Also it's not being displayed correctly in the three Bootstrap columns I need. I could settle for it if there's a way to remedy that.

I copied a random SVG line I found in order to try customizing it.

https://jsfiddle.net/eliranmal/hsfxS/

```html
<svg width="357px" height="2px" viewBox="0 0 300 200">
      <line x1="40" x2="260" y1="100" y2="100" stroke="#5184AF" stroke-width="20" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dasharray="1, 30"/>
      </svg>
```

Nothing shows up. I've seen a suggestion to add `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">` in the head and `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` That didn't help.

Comment: it's showing fine on Chrome

Comment: I opened it in both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: by the way here is some idea with pure CSS : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54378688/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/a/55364821/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/a/48984123/8620333

Comment: remove `px` from width/height and you can remove the height, keep only the width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the viewBox height is 200 while the svg  height is `height="2px"`. The `width` and the `height` of the svg element are not proportional with the `viewBox` size.

One solution would be deleting the height of your svg element:

```css
svg{border:1px solid;}
```

```html
<svg width="357" viewBox="0 0 300 200" >
      <line x1="40" x2="260" y1="100" y2="100" stroke="red" stroke-width="20" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dasharray="1, 30"/>
</svg>
```

Another solution would be changing the value of the `viewBox` height to make it proportional with the `width` and the `height` of the element, Also you need to change the vertical position of the line since otherwise the tine will be drawn outside the `viewBox`. In this case the line is higher than the box so you need to add `svg{overflow:visible}`

```css
svg{overflow:visible;border:1px solid;}
```

```html
<svg width="357" height="20" viewBox="0 0 300 16.8" >
      <line x1="40" x2="260" y1="8.4" y2="8.4" stroke="red" stroke-width="20" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dasharray="1, 30"/>
</svg>
```